# hide div when clicking on div and show second div

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my html code...In this ,i set the to div 'display:none',i just want that when i click on first div which is grey...the second div appear and disappear first and third div and when i click on second div the third and first div disappear....please give me some help..i am new on website designing...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="background:grey">
            text here
        </div>
        <div style="background:blue;display:none">
            text here
        </div>
        <div style="background:green;display:none">
            text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the outer `.col-md-6` div is clicked on you can find the currently visible `div` using the `:visible` selector. You can then `hide()` that, and `show()` the `next()`. Try this:

```
$('.col-md-6').click(function() {
    $(this).find('div:visible').hide().next().show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bb2wdnjp/)

Alternatively, if you don't want to allow someone to hide the final `div`:

```
$('.col-md-6').click(function() {
    var $current = $(this).find('div:visible');
    var $next = $current.next()
    if ($next.length) {
        $current.hide();
        $next.show();
    }
});
```

Or finally, if you want to cycle through all the divs going back to the start once you reach the end:

```
$('.col-md-6').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index') || 1;
    var $divs = $(this).find('div');
    $divs.hide().eq(index % $divs.length).show();
    $(this).data('index', ++index);
});
```

Comment: Thnx @Rory...For such an easy solution...Sir, Is there any way that if i click on first div it disappear with a flip(Y) transition..and same with the second div..?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#blue").hide();
     $("#green").hide();

$("#grey").on("click",function(){
    $("#blue").show(3000);
    $("#grey").hide(2000);
    $("#green").hide(2000);
});
$("#blue").on("click",function(){
   $("#green").show(3000);
    $("#blue").hide(2000);
    $("#grey").hide(2000);
});
$("#green").on("click",function(){
   $("#grey").show(3000);
    $("#blue").hide(2000);
    $("#green").hide(2000);
});

});
</script>



<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="background:grey;height:50px" id="grey">
        text here
    </div>
    <div style="background:blue;height:50px" id="blue">
        text here
    </div>
    <div style="background:green;height:50px" id="green">
        text here
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way that if i click on first div it disappear with a flip(Y) transition..and same with the second div..?

Comment: Please check the below link for teh diffrent transitions

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

I have changed the above code with a transition.